# how to copy a excel sheet by xlrd,xlwt,xlutils with formatting？

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd, xlwt

I can do it by openpyxl, but it is slow.
so I want to ask if is it OK to copy an Excel sheet by xlrd,xlwt,xlutils to a new workbook.

Need to include all formatting information, including merged cells, row numbers, column widths, borders, cell formatting

you can see my openpyxl code below:

```
from copy import copy
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import pathlib


def copy_sheet(file, save_path):

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)  # type:Workbook
    sheet_names = workbook.sheetnames

    new_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    for sheet_name in sheet_names:
        source_worksheet = workbook[sheet_name]  # type: Worksheet
        new_worksheet = new_wb.create_sheet(sheet_name)

        # copy styles
        new_worksheet.sheet_format = source_worksheet.sheet_format
        new_worksheet.sheet_properties = source_worksheet.sheet_properties
        new_worksheet.merged_cells = source_worksheet.merged_cells
        new_worksheet.page_margins = source_worksheet.page_margins
        new_worksheet.page_setup = source_worksheet.page_setup
        new_worksheet.print_options = source_worksheet.print_options

        # copy data to new Sheet
        for row in source_worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=source_worksheet.max_row,
                                              min_col=1, max_col=source_worksheet.max_column):
            for cell in row:
                new_cell = new_worksheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column)
                new_cell.value = cell.value
                new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
                new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
                new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
                new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
        # copy row height and width
        for i in range(1, source_worksheet.max_column + 1):
            new_worksheet.column_dimensions[openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(i)].width = \
                source_worksheet.column_dimensions[openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(i)].width
        for i in range(1, source_worksheet.max_row + 1):
            new_worksheet.row_dimensions[i].height = source_worksheet.row_dimensions[i].height
    new_name = pathlib.Path(file).name
    new_wb.save(f"{save_path}/copied_{new_name}")
```

My purpose is to sort all sheets of an xls file and then save it to a new workbook, which needs to keep the original formatting intact. The sorting is based on the Q12 cell of each sheet.
I have solved the sorting problem, now the problem is how do I copy the sheet with the format

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Also, please read the short descriptions of the tags you add.

Comment: You question mentions `xls file` and `xlrd,xlwt,xlutils` all tools/modules that work only with `xls` files,`Excel versions up to 2003`. However your code being Openpyxl will only work with `xlsx` files, `Excel 2007` and later.

Comment: You question states ***My purpose is to sort all sheets of an xls file and then save it to a new workbook, which needs to keep the original formatting intact.*** If you open a workbook, then sort the sheets you can save the modified workbook to a new [xlsx] file thus keeping the original and creating the new modified file. There is no need to copy sheets to a new workbook.

Comment: hi thanks for you comments. I just want know is there a way to copy sheet directly. All the solutions I've found is to copy cell by cell and then copy the styles info of the cells.

Comment: If you can use `Xlwings` you can copy the sheet complete as you would in Excel using "move/copy sheet". Should be able to do the same with `win32com.client`. If you have a workbook with two or more sheets and you just want to copy one sheet from that workbook to a new workbook, opening the workbook and removing the unwanted sheets then saving that modified workbook with a new name is the same as copying the sheet with all styling and can be achieved with `Openpyxl and Xlwings`. The above comments refer to `xlsx` files only, not `xls` files.